# In what expressions I can use possessions and where I can't (e.g. today's evening-?)

Tags: possessives

1) today **'s** evening ***OR*** today evening

2) today **'s** meeting ***OR*** today meeting

3) meeting **'s** case ***OR*** meeting case

3) winter **'s** weather ***OR*** winter weather

4) market **'s** impact on it ***OR*** market impact on

More information [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/apostrophe). About possessions

Comment: It's difficult to give a complete list of when you use the possessive and when it's just a typical compound noun.  It's "today's meeting" but "winter weather" and "market impact".  There's really no way to answer this effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, a noun can be used as an adjective meaning something of a type associated with this noun. This can be subtly different from a possessive, which indicates a relationship, not necessarily a type.

For example, if you said, "I hate winter weather", that would mean that you hate the type of weather associated with winter, that is, the weather associated with winter in general. But, "I hate this winter's weather" would mean that you hate the weather of this particular winter. Maybe you don't mind winter weather in general, but THIS winter was particularly cold or there was too much snow or whatever.

That said, we generally say:

"today's meeting": the meeting that was or will be held today. It is not a meeting of type today, it is a meeting that is associated with today.

"market impact": the type of impact relevant to markets. It is not an impact associated with this market, it is an impact of type market.

That one could be "market's" if you were talking about a specific market. Like, "What is the oil market's impact on inflation this year?"

We don't say "today's evening"; we say "this evening". I don't know that there's any rule behind that, it's just the convention.

I'm not sure what you mean by a "meeting case" or "meeting's case".

Answer (score 2):

It's ***this evening*** and not today's evening or today evening. It's ***winter*** and not winter weather.

However, if you wonder whether or not an apostrophe *'s'* is to be put, you may have a look on something called *attributive noun*.

In such cases, nouns modify the other nouns and therefore, they go *without* any apostrophe. Examples include:

> market impact 
>  sports car 
>  labor union, and so on...